# What is it called when indefinite pronouns are used as determiner?

Tags: determiners, descriptive-grammar, contemporary-english, indefinite-pronouns

AFAIK it is correct English grammar to say something along the lines of

> Familiarize yourself with everything Apple.

What is this use of *"everything"* called? Is it just a short colloquial form of saying *"everything concerning"*?

Only thing I could find was

> Gretchen enjoys anything sweet.

at the bottom of https://ifioque.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/indefinite-pronoun but it does not further clarify what this is called.

Comment: The structure itself is just a reduced relative clause: "everything that is (related to/named/significant for) Apple". _Everything_ is just the antecedent to the reduced relative. It's nothing special about _everything_.

Comment: I used to get hung up about correctly assigning every usage of a word to a POS category. But one finds that different institutions (even sub-faculties) use different sets, and that anyone who believes that there are not still genuine disputes over what correct assignments actually are (and whether gradience and/or other models are valid) is arguably ill-informed.

Comment: POS: Part Of Speech

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Does that mean it is unclear if this is a valid grammatical construct?

Comment: 'Familiarize yrself w evythng Apple.' passes the 'clarity?' test in Grice's maxim's, which is arguably the first hurdle when gauging acceptability. It arguably sounds acceptable, even good (punchy): arguably the second hurdle (Orwell's Sixth Law). It follows an idiomatic pattern (another early hurdle). But it is arguably extragrammatical. Purists might prefer 'Familiarize yourself with everything [that is] associated with Apple.' And correspondingly, 'Apple' here might be classed as a 'very reduced relative clause' rather than 'adj' / 'n' / 'misc modifier of n' etc. I'd say 'OK informally'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. Combine your comments on this thread and it would make for a pretty good answer. Certainly one I'd accept :)

Comment: But not one I could find convincing supporting references for without an amount of research I'd consider excessive, I'm afraid, leonheess. Hopefully, though, the above is useful; you can research further yourself. POS and gradience are readily searchable at ELU, as are reduced relative clauses.

Answer (score 2):

> What is it called when indefinite pronouns are used as determiner? E.g. “Familiarize yourself with everything Apple.”

**Everything** is not a determiner. It is a pronoun.

“**Everything** Apple” = **all things** that are associated with Apple.

*Apple* is operating as a post-positional attributive noun.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question tho. Also, words can be both pronouns and determiners. To quote Wikipedia: *Indefinite pronouns are associated with indefinite determiners of a similar or identical form (such as every, any, all, some). A pronoun can be thought of as replacing a noun phrase, while a determiner introduces a noun phrase and precedes any adjectives that modify the noun. Thus all is an indefinite determiner in "all good boys deserve favour" but a pronoun in "all are happy".*

Comment: @leonheess *Also, words can be both pronouns and determiners.* I think you have misread the article. As a determiner, the word would have to act in an adjectival manner and have an associated NP. It is clear here that "everything" is an NP/substantive.

Comment: @leonheess  'Indefinite pronouns are associated with indefinite determiners of a similar or identical form' is talking about intercategorial polysemy. 'All men are selfish' and 'All are selfish' use determiner/determinative 'all' and pronoun 'all' respectively. Some would argue they're different words, as with run [n] and run [v] etc..

Answer (score 1):

My view is that in the phrase

> Familiarize yourself with everything Apple

the word 'Apple' is used as a modifier. Think of an Apple device, an Apple style, a quintessentially Apple way of doing business etc.

I think that 'everything Apple' is of the same construction as

something/someone + modifier

which is of course common.

Comment: No, *Apple* is not an adjective. You’ll no more ever have a watch that is Apple than you will a baby who is food or a sitter who is house, yet you can still have *Apple watches, baby food,* and *house sitters.* Sometimes nouns can modify other nouns, and in all these cases, they do do that.  **Just because something modifies a noun *does ɴᴏᴛ mean* it ‘must’ be an adjective❗** The grammatical role is modifier, but the part of speech of these modifiers I’ve just demonstrated is noun. *Unfinished home squatters* are squatters of unfinished homes—ɴᴏᴛ people who are themselves somehow unfinished.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, will replace adjective with modifier in the answer